# Proving Vectors are Perpendicular

Tags: geometry

I am working on geometry concepts. My question is below.

How to prove that vectors $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ are perpendicular if $ac + bd = 0$?

Comment: this is the dot product and if the product is zero then the vectors are perpendicular

Answer (score 3):

You have a triangle with squared sides $a^2+b^2$, $c^2+d^2$ and $(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2$. Now use the cosine rule to show that $\cos{\theta}$ is zero if and only if $ac+bd=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for two vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$, we have:

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = ||\vec{a}||||\vec{b}||\cos(\theta)$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Now in general, $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular iff $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Then we have $$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = ||\vec{a}||||\vec{b}||\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$

So $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular iff $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} =0$

Let $\vec{a} = \binom{a}{b}$, let $\vec{b} = \binom{c}{d}$

Then $$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = ac + bd$$

We are given that $$ac+bd = 0$$

So then it follows that $$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0$$ and hence $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular

Answer (score 0):

Given any vectors $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n), (b_1, b_2,\cdots,b_n)$, the "dot product" or "inner product" is defined to be $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)\cdot(b_1, b_2,\cdots,b_n) = a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\cdots+a_nb_n$. If the dot product of two vectors is zero, you know they're perpendicular.

Suppose you have a triangle with sides given by $u = (a, b), v = (c, d)$, and $u-v$.

First note the length of $u$ is $|u| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and $|v| = \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$. The length of the third edge is $|u-v| = \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2} = \sqrt{a^2-2ac+c^2+b^2-2bd+d^2} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$, because $ac+bd=0$. Clearly this triangle satisfies Pythagoras' Theorem, as $|u-v|^2 = |u|^2+|v|^2$, so it is a right angled triangle (with $u$ perpendicular to $v$ as required).